# How to decode this url parameter from .dll

Tags: asp.net, http, xmlhttprequest, http-headers

I was tried url decode and some online tools, But It not working, Does any one know how to decode/encode this format?

i.dll?1=22202A2F&2=2428&3=5C5F2727595925&5=5B5A5C5E5A&8=4853&9=5E5E5A59

in that form submit using Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded